# hasManyThrough with an intermediate pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

#### Description:

My application is structured as follows:
`Property` has a Many-Many relationship with `Manager`, and a `Unit` has a One-Many relationship with a `Property`, i.e. A manager can manage multiple properties, one property can have multiple manager accounts and one property can have multiple units.

I would like to have a HasManyThrough relationship on the manager to get all his units, so ideally it would look something like: `$manager->units` instead of having through loop through each property and call `$property->units` on it. Is this possible with the current version of laravel?

#### Tables:

managers:

- id

properties:

- id

managers_properties:

- manager_id
- property_id

units:

- id
- property_id

Comment: @GabMic I have looked through the documentation but from my understanding I would need a `manager_id` column on the properties table, which is not the case here

Comment: Then im afraid that laravel wont serve you a native "laravely" way to do so.  @Mauricio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eloquent currently does not have methods for chained relations, other than the `hasManyThrough`, that is only applicable to 2 chained `hasMany` relations. You should create your own implementation to fetch the related resources. The simplest way is to define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on the `Manager` model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

/**
 * @property-read Collection|\App\Models\Property[] $properties
 * @property-read Collection|\App\Models\Unit[] $units
 */
class Manager extends Model
{
    public function properties(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
    }

    public function getUnitsAttribute(): Collection
    {
        return $this->properties
            ->pluck('units')
            ->flatten(1)
            ->unique('id')
            ->sortBy('id');
    }
}
```

You should now be able to access the related units with `$manager->units` assuming `$manager instanceof App\Models\Manager`.

---

**Note**

Calling `$manager->units` *does* perform at most `n + 1` database queries: `1` for fetching `n` related properties, and another `n` for fetching related units for each returned property. "At most" because the resources might have been loaded already because of previous calls to the accessor.

**Note**

Calling `$manager->units` returns you a `Collection` of `Unit` models, a format that's equivalent to what you'd get from the magic accessor of a to-many relationship method. However `getUnitsAttribute()` is *not* an actual relationship method (it does not return a relationship object), so it can not be treated as such, whereas `Manager::properties()` can be.

Comment: Interesting solution, better than what I had in mind. I'll probably post on their github with a proposal for a hasManyThroughPivot relationship, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/808 if you want to join the discussion, credit given to you